# object-fit not working inside flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, object-fit

I have an `img` inside an `article`. The `article` height is the same as the `body` minus the top `nav` (variable, of course). The only way I've found for `object-fit` to work is to put a fixed height in the `article`, which doesn't make sense, since its height is dynamic.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#navTop {
  background:lightgreen;
}
main {
  background:gray;
  padding:0.5em;
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  align-items:stretch;
}
#navLeft {
  background:beige;
  min-width:25vw;
  max-width:25vw;
}
article {
  background:#ffdd80;
  flex:1;
  /*height:90vh;  /*uncomment that line to see it working*/
}
article img {
  height:100%;
  object-fit:scale-down;
}
```

```html
<nav id='navTop'>Title</nav>
<main>
  <nav id='navLeft'>
    Menu
  </nav>
  <article>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/White-beardedHermit.jpg' />
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: min-height:0 to main

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you! Such a simple answer.

Comment: no one told *you are supposed* to find the duplicate. the duplicate feature exist because *you* cannot find it and some of us know how to find it. (it's me who clsoed your question)